# Find any intersection in a list of character vectors

Tags: r, list, reduce, intersect

I have a `list` of `character` `vector`s, some which have intersecting elements, but there aren't necessarily intersecting elements across the entire `list`.

For example:

```
l <- list(c("a"),c("a","b"),c("a","c"),c("d"),c("e"),c("h","i"))
```

I would like to find any intersecting elements. For this example this would be:
`a`

Obviously

```
Reduce(intersect,l)
```

Isn't suited fo that because it looks for elements intersecting across the entire `list`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each element in the list find out it's count using `table` and select only those values that occur in more than one list.

```
vals <- unique(unlist(l))

intersect_vals <- names(Filter(function(x) x > 1, 
                  rowSums(sapply(l, function(x) table(factor(x, vals))) > 0)))

intersect_vals
#[1] "a"
```